# Lua convert format "X h X min" to seconds in WoW

Tags: time, lua, world-of-warcraft

So in the game World of Warcraft I have managed to get the remaining time of a mission via their API. The problem for me is that I want to convert this to seconds to then be able to check at which time the mission will finish. If I call the function `time()` in the game I get a response similar to this 1418569973 which to me, makes no sense. But this is why I need to convert it to seconds, because then I can simply add the amount of seconds I get to the current time and get the end time of the mission.

But my problem is that the when I look into the table that gives me the current time left of a mission it returns a string with the format "X h X min" for example "4 h 34 min". I need to convert that to seconds but I literally have no idea on where to start. I'm thinking of something like removing the "h" and the "min" in a function. But from there I'm not really sure of where to go.

Comment: It's better to use a little piece of code to describe the exact problem.

Comment: Problem was that I didn't have any code to begin with as I didn't know how to approach the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`os.time()` returns the seconds [since epoch](http://www.lua.org/pil/22.1.html). Thus, "1418569973" gives you ["12/14/14 03:12:53 PM" UTC](http://codepad.org/LTt5mSJy). Now, to convert your string to seconds:

```
local iH, iM = sInput:match "(%d+) h (%d+) min"
iH, iM = tonumber( iH ), tonumber( iM )
local iSec = iH * 3600 + iM * 60
```

Comment: Would you please explain how the first line works, what is sInput:match? How does it work?

Comment: nvm, got it working! Had to replace sInput with the variable I got from the API. Thanks!